# Products with Multiple Categories throwing error in Cart

Tags: product, shopping-cart

My client is having an issue where they have products assigned to multiple categories, and the Shopping Cart page throws an error when you add one of these products to the cart.

[image]

I'm aware that these category assingments are probably not optimal, however, I was under the impression it shouldn't be causing a problem like this.

the error we get back is from this file

/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php :

```
SQLSTATE[21000]: Cardinality violation: 1241 Operand should contain 1 column(s), query was: SELECT `catalog_category_flat_store_1`.* FROM `catalog_category_flat_store_1` WHERE (`catalog_category_flat_store_1`.`entity_id`='4', '11', '19', '26')
```

which shows me that the WHERE clause us designed to accept only one ID value, but it is being given a list of IDs

My impression is that having multiple categories is not normally an issue. Does anyone here recognize this issue and where I might go to rectify it?

note: we are using a Shipping Rules plugin from Amasty, I can't say for sure this isn't the problem

Answer (score 0):

This is good extension but I think extension is not properly install at magento.Delete the extension first as well as tables related to this extension. After install new version of this extesnion.

Note: You can take help support from Amasty.